# Entity Framework DbContext getting disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, objectlistview

I have a little program that uses [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) to visualise the database information. Currently I am trying to add items and keep getting `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` Which is highlighting the `olvEntityTypes.AddObject(et);` line below.

**Code:**

```
string typeName = tbTypeName.Text;
string desc = tbDesc.Text;

EntityTypes et;
using (FCERTSModelContainer db = new FCERTSModelContainer())
{
    // Create and save new row for the EntityTypes table.
    et = new EntityTypes { EntityTypeName = typeName, Description = desc };
    db.EntityTypes.Add(et);
    db.SaveChanges();

    olvEntityTypes.AddObject(et);
}
```

- I suspected that `SaveChanges()` might also be closing the context, but trying to add the object before saving changes still throws the same error.
- Putting `olvEntityTypes.AddObject(et);` outside of the `using` block is also a failure.
- If I query the database with something like the following, no errors are thrown;

**Code:**

```
var query = from ent in db.EntityTypes
            orderby ent.EntityTypeName
            select ent;

olvEntityTypes.SetObjects(query);
```

So I'm at a bit of a loss now as to why this is throwing errors and how to fix it.

Comment: It's just an ObjectListView. I haven't touched it apart from mapping the columns, which is all done through the GUI/designer. I'm not sure why it would even need the DbContext for AddObject but not for SetObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the initial setting of objects for the objectlistview. I was using this piece of code;

```
var query = db.EntityTypes.OrderBy(eg => eg.EntityTypeName);
olvEntityTypes.SetObjects(query);
```

Which works fine, but is in a different `using` block in my codebase and as such, a completely different DbContext.

If I convert the query to a List and then call `SetObjects()` the entire program works without fault.